# laravel zizaco/entrust how to go about doing sublogins/child login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

Hi im using zizaco/entrust in laravel. I'm looking to setup group login roles for example I am trying to build something that will help me manage my projects.

I want to be able to allow clients to login to have read only access to the pages i specify and not other users data. Therefore I would need to allow users that register to create extra users and assign roles etc.

Obviously I would need to create an extra table to store and handle client logins. But I'm not sure how to implement this.

I suppose what I'm looking for to have is a parent account and then child account logins.

Does anyone know of any examples they can forward me to so I can have a look and see how this has been implemented? Or does someone have a basic solution that they could share? Or any help in general.

Answer (score 3):

This is a roadmap for you.

Create an ACL table, model and add that table, which user can access which content

Here is an example table structure:

```
id | userId | contentId | contentTable
```

And you can use laravel controller filters for access control.

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters

Here is an example filter for ACL

```
Route::filter('ACL', function($route, $request, $contentId, $contentTable) {

$haveAccess = ACL::where('userId', Auth::user()->id,)->where('contentId', $contentId)->where('contentTable', $contentTable)->get();
if (count($haveAccess) < 1) {
    return false;
}

return true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for a group based permission system. Typically what I do in these situations is I create a users table, a group table, and a permissions table.

I then create pivot tables between users and groups, and permissions and groups and let Laravel manage those for me. A pivot table should consist of it's own unique id column, a user_id, and group_id, and your standard created_at, and updated_at. I include active and deleted_at as well. deleted_at is required for soft delete.

Basically what you end up with is users belong to groups, and permissions belong to groups.

So you create three modules, User(should already exist), Group, Permission. An example from the User Module is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';
/**
 * Enable/Disable $softDelete: Disabled by default.
 *
 * @var boolean
 */ 
protected $softDelete = true;
/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password');

/**
 * Create Relationship with Groups Table
 * @return Groups Many-to-many relationship
 */
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Group')->withPivot('active');
}
```

Do this for Group, and Permission as well.

Note: That the ->withPivot('active'); is saying include the field active from my Group DB when pulling data from the pivot table. Typically pivot tables will only return the id associations.

Groups can be anything you want, basically a name, a description and an id, with the standard created_at updated_at active/deleted_at fields. For permissions, I actually add in the route's they have access to. So the permissions table just consists of the name of a route, and the actual route such as '/admin/index'.

Once I have these setup, I create an role filter that checks to see what groups the user is associated with, and then i check to see what permissions those groups have. I stick this filter in the __Constructor of my controllers, so every time any resource is accessed it checks to verify the user is in fact allowed to access that section, if not, I use a flash data with a redirect.

Filter in filters.php:

```
Route::filter('check_roles', function(){
//detect current route
$route = Route::currentRouteName();

//Laravel gives too much data with the currentRouteName so you'll want to do some reformatting of the $route to match what you put in the DB.

//set some helper variables
$access = false;
$active = false;

//get user id to determine groups
$userID = Auth::user()->id;

//get groups user belongs to
$groups = User::find($userID)->groups;

//now that we know the groups, let's loop through each group and all it's permission and see if our current route and a permission matches
foreach($groups as $group){
    $permissions = Group::find($group->id)->permissions;
    foreach($permissions as $permission){

        if($permission->action == trim($action)){
            $access = true;
            if($permission->pivot->active === '1'){
                $active = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
//If we found a match, access would be true, if not redirect back to their originating page. they do not have access to view resource
//We have two scenarios, they don't have access period, or they did have access but it was disabled for some reason. 
if($access){
    if(!$active){
        //return to previous page;
        return Redirect::back()->with('message','This permission has been disabled in your account.');
    }
}else if(!$access){
    //return to previous page;
    return Redirect::back()->with('message','You do not have the proper clearence to access this resource.');
}

//if the user isn't redirected, then they have proper access.

 });
```

Filter in controller:

```
$this->beforeFilter('check_roles', array('except' => array('methodToIgnore','methodToIgnore','methodToIgnore')));
```

Now for your actual implementation, you can create custom groups for the client users, who can create new users (a specific route they can access) and setup the *create user* form to automatically put the users that client creates in a group that has read only access to the site.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.